# Child objects in partial keeps coming up as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am making a UI that takes in user information and spits out a JSON file (as well as posting the data to a database).  The UI has a form that gathers all the data and then the associated controller pushes that data through Newtonsoft to produce JSON.  The problem is the child tables keep appearing as "null" in the JSON and I think I've set up my partial views incorrectly.

Here's the base model, `NPPR_Provider`:

```
 [Table("NPPR_Provider", Schema ="AD")]
    public class NPPR_Provider : Provider
    {
        //...
        public NPPR_ServLocation NPPR_ServLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Provider's direct child is `NPPR_ServLocation`.  The other properties I omitted were just primary and foreign keys.  The base class "Provider" simply provides all the column names shared between the different types of provider my company has.

`NPPR_ServLocation`'s fields display fine in the resulting JSON, but it's children do not.

```
public class NPPR_ServLocation
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServLocationId { get; set; }
        public int NPPRProvId { get; set; }
        public string EnrollmentType { get; set; }

        //... more column names that work as intended

        //Child Tables:
        public List<NPPR_Address> Address { get; set; }
        public List<NPPR_NPIAssociations> NPIAssociations { get; set; }
        //... more table names that do not work as intended
    }
```

The table names work fine for fetching data, so I don't think the problem is there.  It's in setting the data where I'm running into this problem.  All of these tables appear as "null" in the resulting JSON.

Here's how, for example, the NPI Associations model is passed from the primary view to its specific partial:

Primary view:

```
using Company.Namespace.Application.Models
@model NPPR_Provider

<section class="container">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("NPPRJsonFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id="NPPRTemplateForm", @onsubmit="validateNPPRTemplate(event)" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.Partial(partialFormsDir + "ServiceProvider")
        @Html.Partial(partialFormsDir + "ServiceLocation")
        @Html.Partial(partialFormsDir + "NPIAssoc", Model.NPPR_ServLocation.NPIAssociations)
        //... etc
```

And in the NPIAssoc cshtml:

```
@using Company.Namespace.Application.Models
@model List<NPPR_NPIAssociations>

<div class="form-group">
    <h3 class="aetna-brand-heading">NPI Associations</h3>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="npiHTML">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NPI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NPI, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "NPI", @class = "form-control", maxlength = 10, required = true } })
        <small class="help-block">Ten digit identifier, numeric values only</small>
    </div>
    // ...etc
```

And the associated model:

```
[Table("NPPR_NPIAssociations", Schema = "AD")]
    public class NPPR_NPIAssociations : NPI_Associations
    {
        [Key]
        public int NPIAssocId { get; set; }
        public int ServLocationId { get; set; }
    }

public abstract class NPI_Associations
    {
        [Display(Name = "NPI Association")]
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string NPI { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally, the controller itself:

```
public ActionResult NPPRJsonFile(NPPR_Provider provider)
        {
            string nppr_file = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(provider);
            ViewData["nppr_json"] = nppr_file;
            return View("NPPRJsonFile");
        }
```

For some reason, when I fill out the form and submit, all of the child tables of `NPPR_ServLocation` are coming into the JSON as "null".  Not the fields with in them, the models themselves.  Even with all the input fields properly filled in.

```
"NPPR_ServLocation":{
    "ServLocationId":0,
    "NPPRProvId":0,
    "EnrollmentType":"I",
    "ProviderLocationId":null,
    "ProviderTypeCode":"29",
    "OrganizationType":"H",
    "Address":null,
    "IRSTaxAssociations":null,
    "NPIAssociations":null,
}
```

You can see, starting at `Address`, they're all null.  And they're all set up the same way NPIAssociations is set up as I showed above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `public NPPR_ServLocation() { this. NPIAssociations = new List< NPPR_NPIAssociations >(); }` make the output json `[]` instead of `null`?

Comment: If I do that, yes, it produces `[]` but then it breaks my queries because Entity Framework is expecting an auto property.

Comment: I modified the model so the constructor initializes them to `new List<NPPR_*>()` and now they all return empty arrays, without breaking the queries.  Still, they shouldn't be empty arrays in JSON if I provide data.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a cut-down example that can be tested locally? Also where is the serialization with NewtonSoft?